# Adding skill tests for initial reputation points boost

Tags: feature-request, reputation, new-users, privileges

I would like to suggest adding some field-related tests similar to ones that are commonly available on freelancing sites so that newcomers can get an initial boost in rating. Something like earning badges, for example.

I've been using Stack Overflow for a long time, but I didn't register until recently and, although I have experience and knowledge with a lot of things, it's still a bit frustrating getting initial reputation to unlock some features.

This could also help on the career site. Something like having badges with uploading certificates, diplomas or passing some online tests would be good feedback for employers.

Comment: Don't use your Stack Overflow reputation as your resume.

Comment: That would be an easy way to create voting sock puppets. Create ten accounts, cheat to find the "correct" answers, and boost all those accounts up to the level where they could vote for you. Also, how could we possibly create skill tests for the enormous breadth of technologies represented by this site?

Comment: *although I have a experience and knowledge with a lot of things it's still a bit frustrating getting initial reputation to unlock some features.* - if we are going to make it this easy to unlock the features, we might as well not lock them in the first place. And they are 'locked' for a reason

Comment: "I've seen some LPs of this game and I think it's cool. Now how can I get a high-level avatar without having to go to the trouble of playing the game myself?"

Comment: @BoltClock buy your weapon unlocks and level upgrades with microtransactions here!

Comment: The idea wasn't to use stack overflow as a resume but it could be used for  the careers site.

Comment: This would only work if the privileges were bumped up by the same amount of free rep you get from said badges, thus nulling the effect you're going for.

Comment: Reputation on Stack Overflow (and all Stack Exchange sites) is a measure of how trusted you are by the system. Being knowledgeable about the site's topic isn't the same thing as knowing how to participate on site.

Comment: @BoltClock Pay extra money to EA, *obviously*.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a poor idea for several reasons:

- Any skill test that is simple enough so that we can automate it can be gamed by a bot, making it very easy to create large quantities of voting/downvoting/trolling sock puppets.
- Stack Overflow represents a completely ungraspable range of technologies. A prodigy in iOS programming could be the biggest and dirtiest noob of all times in C++, and vice versa.
- Stack Overflow is not fit as reference for job applications.
- If you are informed and start working on it, you'll be to garner reputation where you can do most things in absolutely no time.

Edit (powered by meagar's comment):

- Most importantly, and the thing that seems to continually be missed, reputation points are not a measure of skill. It's a measure of how much we trust you to perform various levels of moderation duty on the site. A skill-testing quiz has nothing at all to do with reputation points.

Comment: Most importantly, and the thing that seems to continually be missed, reputation is **not a measure of skill**. It's a measure of how much we trust you to perform various levels of moderation duty on the site. A skill-testing quiz has nothing at all to do with reputation.

Comment: `Stackoverflow is not fit as reference for job applications.` - This should be on TechCrunch tomorrow.